# How to use the same ADO pipeline for deploying to dev, staging and production

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm using ADO to trigger tests and deployments to Google App Engine when I push to Github. Note that I use the same .yaml file to run 2 stages; the first being Test and the second, Deploy. The reason I am not using release pipelines is because the docs suggest that release pipelines are the "classic" way of doing things, and besides, having the deploy code in my yaml means I can version control it (as opposed to using ADO's UI)

I have already set up the 2 stages and they work perfectly fine. However, the deploy right now only works for my dev environment. I wish to use the same stage to deploy to my other environments (staging and production).

Here's what my .yaml looks like:

```
trigger:
    # list of triggers
stages:
 - stage 'Test'
   pool: 'ubuntu-latest'
   jobs:
     - job: 1
     - job: 2
     - job: 3

 - stage 'Deploy'
   jobs: 
    - job: 'Deploy to dev'
```

I could potentially do a deploy to staging and production by copying the `Deploy to dev` job and creating similar jobs for staging and production, but I really want to avoid that because the deployment jobs are pretty huge and I'd hate to maintain 3 separate jobs that all do the same thing, albeit slightly differently. For example, one of the things that the dev jobs does is copy app.yaml files from `<repo>/deploy/dev/module/app.yaml`. For a deploy to staging, I'd need to have the same job, but use the staging directory: `<repo>/deploy/staging/module/app.yaml`. This is a direct violation of the DRY (don't repeat yourself) principle.

So I guess my questions are:

1. Am I doing the right thing by choosing to not use release-pipelines and instead, having the deploy code in my yaml?
2. Does my azure-pipelines.yaml format look okay?
3. Should I use [variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch), set them to either dev, staging, and production in a `dependsOn` job, then use these variables to replace  the directories where I copy the files from? If I do end up using this though, setting the variables will be a challenge.

Comment: You could define the deploy job in a template that you reference using a `- template: deploy.yml` step from all three deployment jobs. This ensures that you only define the actual release steps in one common place.

Comment: Thanks @mm8! That worked great. Since @Lucas added an answer, I will have to accept his, hope that's okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deploying from the yaml is the right approach, you could also leverage the new "Environment" concept to add special gates and approvals before deploying. See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops) to learn more.

As @mm8 said, using templates here would be a clean way to manage the deployment steps and keep them consistent between environments. You will find more information about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops).